# Installing Windows 8 on Sierra '16 MBP

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, bootcamp, windows

Bootcamp does not recognize anything other than Windows 10 on the new MacBook Pro running Sierra. Anyone know how to get around this? Thanks! I am using Boot Crap version 6.1.0

Comment: What version of Bootcamp are you using? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/85582/bootcamp-5-windows-8-troubles-unsupported-hardware

Comment: I am using 6.1.0

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out I think that you actually do not want to. Because on the new MBPro with Touch bar (great, great, great - way underused device) there is no driver for windows other than for windows 10... Is this correct?...Because the only escape key is on the touchbar, windows 10 is effectively the only option. Any one can confirm my reasoning?